# textFieldColors() deprecated in Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

```
TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {},
    leadingIcon = {
                  Icon( Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = "")
    },
    placeholder = {
                  Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.placeholder_search))
    },
    colors = TextFieldDefualts.textFieldColors(),
    modifier = modifier
        .heightIn(min = 56.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth())
}
```

And also it show error message as `"This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future."`

`TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()` is deprecated and asked me to move it to in Material3 library and after moving to material3, still it shows `textFieldColors()` deprecated.. Any help would be a great help

dependencies added in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')
implementation(composeBom)
androidTestImplementation(composeBom)

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.2'
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
}
```

Comment: You need to use ```TextFieldDefaults.colors()``` rather using ```TextFieldDefaults. textFieldColors()``` in latest material3 design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()` deprecated in Material3 library. we need to migrate to the following call for applying colors in Compose TextField
as `TextFieldDefaults.colors()`

And instead of `backgroundColor =`  as follows :

```
TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {},
    ......
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.color1,
    ),
    ....
}
```

we need to migrate to as follows :

```
TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {},
    ......
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        //setting the text field background when it is focused
        focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.color1,

        //setting the text field background when it is unfocused or initial state
        unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.color1,

        //setting the text field background when it is disabled
        disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.color1,
    ),
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove Redundant Dependency dependency from your build.gradle file.

```kotlin
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0"
```

It's not necessary when using Material3.

- Ensure you're importing from the Material3 library for TextFieldColors:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldColors
```

- Instead of using `TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()`, leverage Material3's ColorScheme API to create a `TextFieldColors` instance:

```kotlin
val colors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.toTextFieldColors()
```

See here -

```
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldColors
// ... other imports

TextField(
   // ... other TextField properties
   colors = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.toTextFieldColors(),
   // ... other TextField properties
)
```